# Make zip of directory contents and name zip same as directory - recursively

Tags: directory, zip

I have over 500 sub directories coming off of one root directory that each contain >6000 files each.  the directories are named `20150218`, `20150217`, etc., one for each day of the year.

I want to develop a script that will zip all of the files in a directory, i.e. `20150217` and name the directory `20150217.zip`.  I then want to delete the original files.

so,  all of the sud directories in `~/public_html/ispy/dlink/` would be zipped separately.

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Well, implement a loop that iterates over all entries of type directory that a directory listing of that base folder contains. Call a zip creator in each iteration. What is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste following script into any unix editor (vim, geany, mousepad) and save it in directory with Your "date" subfolders. Name it as you wish, with no extension e.g. zipscript. From terminal: go to directory with Your script, allow to execute it: `chmod +x zipscript` and fire it: `sudo ./zipscript`.

```
#!/bin/bash

for D in *
do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        zip -r -j "${D}".zip "${D}"
        rm -R "${D}"
    fi
done
```

Script runs as follows: for every file (directory is also a file under unix) in current directory check if it is a directory and, if true, make zip with the same name, then delete subdirectory with all files in it.

Comment: Mr. Rat -This is helpful, i even think i understand the code.  However, I do not understand the chmod+x and sudo parts?  DOes the script need to have any special extension.  I wonder if I might move this to email.  can I write to you via email?

Comment: @user2079583 I've edited my answer to explain more what You have to do. You have to read about bash commands and using linux from console, it's a basic knowledge! And if You think that answer is helpful accept it by clicking a tick.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It works like a champ.  I figured out how to run it last night.  WOW.  Such elegant code to do a relatively big thing.  I am at the beginning of learning this stuff.  Any chance we can chat through email?  you can reach me at buy@paragon-c.com